# Celery 'update_status' function is not working

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am using celery and django-celery-results in my Django application. My celery results are being stored in the backend and this is what celery.py looks like.

```py
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "shoonya_backend.settings")

# Define celery app and settings
celery_app = Celery(
    "shoonya_backend",
    result_backend="django-db",
    accept_content=["application/json"],
    result_serializer="json",
    task_serializer="json",
)

celery_app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
celery_app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

I am trying to update the state of a task from within the celery function if I get an exception as follows.

```py
try: 
    result = resource.import_data(imported_data, raise_errors=True)



    # If validation checks fail, raise the Exception
except Exception as e:

    self.update_state(
        state=states.FAILURE,
        meta={
            "exc_type": type(e).__name__,
            "exc_message": traceback.format_exc().split("\n"),
        },
    )
```

The following command doesn't result in any change in the `TaskResult` table even when the exception is raised and the Task is always a success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have a `FAILURE` state, you need to raise an exception, else you will always have a `SUCCESS` result state. Here you don't raise one, you just update your task status, which is not the same.

Even though you update the state of your task to `FAILURE`, because you then finish the execution of your task without raising any error, it instantly changes to `SUCCESS`.

But raising an exception will finish the execution on the `FAILURE` state you need.

You should have something like that :

```
try: 
    result = resource.import_data(imported_data, raise_errors=True)

except Exception as e:
    raise e # In your backend you'll get a FAILURE state and the traceback
```